# Loading all tables in a MySQL database into an associative array using PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm new to PDO. I need to pass all tables in a MySQL database into an associative PHP array (each its own array, gathered into an umbrella array with the table names as keys).

I am able to fetch the table names easily enough, but my second query, fetching each of the tables in turn, returns nothing, with no apache2 errors. I eventually learned that there is apparently a deliberate limitation on the use of multiple PDO objects, but I am nevertheless stuck trying to get around it. I'll illustrate with two attempts, one with the apparently illegal dual objects, the second a speculative attempt with two statements in one object, using a parameter for the table name. Separating the calls out into two separate functions makes no difference either. I haven't yet got to the point of cleaning up the code with try/catch environments.

```
// Attempt #1: Two separate objects

function getMotifs()
{
    global $themesdb;
    $motifNames = array();
    $showTables = $themesdb->prepare("SHOW TABLES");
    $showTables->execute();
    while ($column = $showTables->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM))
    {
        array_push($motifNames, $column[0]);
    }
    $motifIndex = array();
    foreach ($motifNames as $table)
    {
        $getMotifs = $themesdb->prepare("SELECT * FROM $table");
        $getMotifs->execute();
        while ($item = $getMotifs->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
        {
            $motifIndex[$table] = $item;
        }
    }
    return $motifIndex;
}

    // Attempt #2: One object, two statements, one parameter

function getMotifs()
{
    global $themesdb;
    $motifNames = array();
    $table = "?";
    $showTables = $themesdb->prepare("SHOW TABLES; SELECT * FROM :table");
    $showTables->bindParam(':table', $table, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $showTables->execute();
    while ($column = $showTables->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM))
    {
        array_push($motifNames, $column[0]);
    }
    $motifIndex = array();
    foreach ($motifNames as $table)
    {
        $showTables->execute();
        while ($item = $showTables->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
        {
            $motifIndex[$table] = $item;
        }
    }
    return $motifIndex;
}
```

Comment: ___ALL Table???___

Comment: You don't bother checking the result of your prepare or execute statements in either example. Might want to start there.

Comment: Attempt 2 is invalid PDO as you cannot parameterize a table or column name

Comment: Attempt 1 works for me, so maybe you are just EXPLODING your memory allocation loading everything into a single array all in one go.

Comment: Did you check your ERROR LOG

Comment: No errors in the apache2 or MySQL logs... Almost certainly not a memory issue, as I'm looking at just three tables with three columns and one row each at this point. Today I'm going to try organizing my data differently so I can select rows instead of tables.